# How to create route in right way?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I need to create 2 route

`/users/philosophy`

`/topic/philosophy`

On `/users/` there is a list of categories and on `topic` is a list of categories. On `/users/philosophy` there is list of users by category and the same for topic. Categories are same. So I created router:

```
this.resource('categories', { path: '/:section' }, function(){
    this.resource('category', {path: '/:url'});
});
```

And it works.
But now I want to add filter `/users/philosophy/top` for list of users. I tried to do it like that:

```
this.resource('categories', { path: '/:section' }, function(){
    this.resource('category', {path: '/:url/:filter'});
});
```

But if remove segment `top` from url, it throw error, so `filter` param became necessary.
How can I make `filter` param unnecessary? Or please another way to build router.

Comment: Just a tip - do not use `resource`, replace it with `route`. Resource will be deprecated soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are talking about ember [query params](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/routing/query-params/).

```
App.CategoriesCategory = Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['filter'],
  filter: '' /* default value */
});
```

and to transit user to this route with `filter` parameter use following helper

```
{{#link-to 'categories.category' url (query-params filter="top")}}Show top{{/link-to}}
```

if you do not want to use the parameter then skip query params.